# Use multiple tabs in h2 console

Tags: database, h2

I am using h2 console

[image]

how can I have multiple tabs, with one query per tab? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 Console doesn't have tabs by itself, this is a very old tool.

You can only open multiple tabs with H2 Console in your browser and login into each of them separately.

(It isn't possible with unnamed connection-private databases with URL `jdbc:h2:mem:`, in that case each tab will have an own database instead of shared one.)